# How to create a Method that creates a new List and takes additional parameters

Tags: c#, list, methods, parameters

Is there a way to create a `Method` that creates a new instance of a `List` as a `Method Parameter`and does something with the new `List`?

```
    private void ApplyMaxValue(List<double> list, double myDouble, Border border) 
    {
        list = new List<double>();
        list.Add(myDouble * 8);
        border.Width = list.Max();
    }
```

I would like to be able to pass values like this where `someListToCreate` is created in the `Method` rather than using an existing list.

```
    ApplyMaxValue(someListToCreate, aDouble, myBorder);
```

I am still a little new to C# and not sure if `Methods` are capable of this or if I would need to create a `Class`.

**EDIT**

Code with demonstration of Method

```
<Window x:Class="NewListSample.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="500" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel Margin="20">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
            <Border x:Name="borderForArray1" BorderThickness="1" Height="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="20" Background="#FFF57F7F" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
                <Border  x:Name="borderForArray2" BorderThickness="1" Height="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="20" Background="#FF6FA8D6" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
                <Border x:Name="borderForArray3" BorderThickness="1" Height="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="20" Background="#FFEEB382" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
                <Border x:Name="borderForArray4" BorderThickness="1" Height="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="20" Background="#FFB171E6" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
        </StackPanel>
            <Button Content="Generate" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Padding="8,3" Margin="0,5,0,0" Click="Button_Click"/>
            <Button Content="Method" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Padding="8,3" Margin="0,5,0,0" Click="Button_Click_1" />
            <Button Content="Clear" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Padding="8,3" Margin="0,5,0,0" Click="Button_Click_2"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

CS

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace NewListSample
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        string[] array1 = { "This is a word.", "This is a sentence.", "This is short.", "This is." };
        string[] array2 = { "This is a word.", "This is a very very very very long sentence.", "This is the longest sentence in this array along with all other arrays in this sample.", "This is a string." };
        string[] array3 = { "This.", "That.", "Those.", "These.", "Slightly longer string." };
        string[] array4 = { "a.", "b.", "c.", "defg." };


        //Prevent from writing this code
        List<double> list1 = new List<double>();
        List<double> list2 = new List<double>();
        List<double> list3 = new List<double>();
        List<double> list4 = new List<double>();
        //Prevent code end


        //Method to prevent writing longer code
        private void ApplyMaxValue(string[] array, Border border)
        {
            List<double> someList = new List<double>();

            foreach (string s in array)
            {
                someList.Add(s.Length * 3);
            }

            border.Height = someList.Max();
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (string s in array1)
            {
                list1.Add(s.Length * 3);
            }

            foreach (string s in array2)
            {
                list2.Add(s.Length * 3);
            }

            foreach (string s in array3)
            {
                list3.Add(s.Length * 3);
            }

            foreach (string s in array4)
            {
                list4.Add(s.Length * 3);
            }

            borderForArray1.Height = list1.Max();
            borderForArray2.Height = list2.Max();
            borderForArray3.Height = list3.Max();
            borderForArray4.Height = list4.Max();
        }

        private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ApplyMaxValue(array1, borderForArray1);
            ApplyMaxValue(array2, borderForArray2);
            ApplyMaxValue(array3, borderForArray3);
            ApplyMaxValue(array4, borderForArray4);
        }

        private void Button_Click_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            borderForArray1.Height = borderForArray2.Height = borderForArray3.Height = borderForArray4.Height = 1;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to pass the list as a parameter

```
private void ApplyMaxValue(double myDouble, Border border) 
{
    List<double> list = new List<double>();
    list.Add(myDouble * 8);
    border.Width = list.Max();
}
```

if you want to use the list after using this method you can use:

```
private List<double> ApplyMaxValue(double myDouble, Border border) 
{
    List<double> list = new List<double>();
    list.Add(myDouble * 8);
    border.Width = list.Max();
    return list
}
```

Comment: This works for a one time use but will not create an new instance of another List.

Comment: Yes it would , the return operation will return you a new list to your main method

Comment: I have accepted your answer since it was first and works after doing some testing.

Comment: The first method here is a bit odd - why create a new list and then just find the maximum value in it when there'll only be a single value, which you already know? That first method is basically `border.Width = myDouble;`.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you should be *returning* the list reference, rather than using it as a parameter - otherwise the fact that you're assigning a different value to it in the first statement of the method body makes it pointless:

```
private List<double> ApplyMaxValue(double myDouble, Border border) 
{
    List<double> list = new List<double>();
    list.Add(myDouble * 8);
    border.Width = list.Max();
    return list;
}
```

Admittedly it's not obvious to me why you'd use `list.Max()` here when the only element is `myDouble`...

If you meant you want to accept a list as a method parameter but you *don't* need to create a new list, you can just use:

```
private void ApplyMaxValue(List<double> list, double myDouble, Border border) 
{
    list.Add(myDouble * 8);
    border.Width = list.Max();
}
```

It's still not entirely clear why you'd want a single method to do that - it feels like it doesn't really have one responsibility. But it will at least work...

Comment: I am unable to get this working. The reason I am using this to add double values from a for loop into the `Method`. The `Method` would then add these values to a `List` and get the Max value then apply to another object. I have multiple objects that this applies to. So writing a one line `Method` for each object I need will be more convenient.

Comment: The value of `myDouble` changes every time in the loop.

Comment: @MiddleCSharp: If you're adding multiple values, surely you only need to work out the maximum value at the end of the loop. But anyway, you haven't said what problem you're having with either of the suggestions I've already made.

Comment: This works based on the question. Izikon's answer came first with similar code so I have accepted his answer. I will post sample code to demonstrate the purpose of this question.

Comment: @MiddleCSharp: Well actually my answer was 4 minutes before lzikon's, but that's not really the best way of determining which answer to accept. Accept whichever answer helped you most.

Comment: his answer prevented the need for a return value. Which is simpler and still works for the question asked.

Comment: @MiddleCSharp: Well, both of our answers have both options. This is the problem with your question being a bit vague (because you asked about creating a new list). I'm fine with you accepting the other answer - just be clear about why. (Doing it on the basis of time would be inaccurate and isn't really the best criterion, in my view.) Also read my comment about the first method in that answer - it's not really sensible, IMO.

Comment: I appreciate you answering the question. And you're right, your answer came first when I check the timestamps and it is a working solution. But as I mentioned, Izikon's code was simpler. It `prevented` the need for a `return value` and I didn't have to make the method a `List<double>`.

Comment: @MiddleCSharp: I'm confused. Have you seen the second method in my answer, which accepts a `List<double>` parameter and has a `void` return type? If you don't want to either return a list or accept one as a parameter, I'm even more confused than before about what you were actually requiring...

Comment: Please check the example code to see how a new list is needed for every array. None of the answers solved my original problem but for the question that I asked, these are working solutions.

Comment: @MiddleCSharp: Well your final code looks pretty much like my comment here: "If you're adding multiple values, surely you only need to work out the maximum value at the end of the loop." Anyway, it doesn't matter... but please try to be clearer when asking questions next time.